# Keycloak realm login page is not appearing

Tags: keycloak

I'm trying keycloak and it's not easy :)
I've a problem with realm login page, login for admin panel is working perfect.
I'm running keycloak with docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
    postgres:
       image: postgres:12.2
       container_name: postgres
       environment:
         POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
         POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
         POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

    keycloak:
      image: jboss/keycloak:10.0.1
      container_name: keycloak
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
        DB_ADDR: postgres
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_PASSWORD: password
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: password
        PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
         - postgres

    mailhog:
      image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
      container_name: mailhog
      ports:
        - "8025:8025"
```

I'm starting it with command docker-compose up --build and everything is starting.
I'm login as an admin and after that I'm creating realm with name myapp. After that I just want to see a realm login page, so I'm opening the link: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myapp/protocol/openid-connect/auth
and what I see is We are sorry...

[image]

I was looking for some answers in google but I didn't find any.
Do I need some additional profile config to make it work?

I also watch this but didn't help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duawSV69LDI here it seems working just like that.

Is any body have an idea what I can do?

Best regards!

Answer (score 26):

The error message suggests, that the URL to the admin console, to which you are trying to connect directly, is wrong. You can obtain the correct URL to the realm's console by

1. Log in to the master realm
2. Switch to your realm "myapp"
3. Navigate to (Configure) Clients. You should see a client ID named "security-admin-console". (It should be created by default when you created the realm.)
   Use its URL.

Answer (score 8):

I found out answer to my question here:

https://robferguson.org/blog/2019/12/24/getting-started-with-keycloak/

and it's this link I was looking for:

http://localhost:10001/auth/realms/development/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_NAME&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/authorization-code/callback

I can log in and I'm getting code from keycloak server

Comment: Update: in keycloak above 19 just remove first /auth after port

Comment: Updated URL: https://rob-ferguson.me/getting-started-with-keycloak/

Comment: rob blog is not updated with the last changes from keycloak > 19

Answer (score 8):

Using the dockerized version of Keycloack, the user login url for the newly-created realm and user was:

```
http://localhost:[port]/realms/[realm-name]/account
```

Which in my case was

```
http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm/account
```

Comment: Which version are you using? It's great that in newer ones keycloak support two factor authentication out of the box, I really recommend that one.

Answer (score 1):

Brief steps:

1. Select which SSO protocol you want to use SAML vs OIDC
2. Create SAML/OIDC client in the Keycloak with configuration, which will fits your SSO app needs
3. Configure client from 2.) in your SSO app
4. Login through your SSO app - your app generates correct parameters (response_type, client_id, state, ....) - it isn't simple
   URL without URL parameters (actually, it can be - for example SAML IDP
   initiated login, but it must be properly configured on the client
   level)

Answer (score 0):

You can find here detailed instructions how to integrate Keycloak with external OIDC Providers: https://ultimatesecurity.pro/tags/oidc/

This link will explain how to integrate Keycloak with external SAML Providers: https://ultimatesecurity.pro/tags/saml/